# Running dependency job using bsub only when file exists

Tags: linux, unix, lsf

I need to run the job using "bsub" command.
I am running two scripts, at the end of first script (script_1.tcl) I am creating a file i.e. NEW_FILE. The second script (script_2.tcl) should be fired only when script_1.tcl is executed successfully and the file "NEW_FILE" exists in the current working directory otherwise it should wait till the file (NEW_FILE) is created.
If the first job exits before creating the NEW_FILE then second job should not be fired.
I am trying this, but it's showing that "dependency condition syntax error".

```
bsub -Ip -J "job_1" tclsh script_1.tcl ; bsub -Ip -w "file(exist(NEW_FILE))" tclsh script_2.tcl
```

OS    - Unix/Linux
Shell - csh

Thank you.

Comment: for solaris running csh it's `if(-e $file) then bsub etc endif`

Comment: the actual case is, I need to run second job only when first job is done (completed) and file exists(File is generated at the end of first job). bsub -Ip -J "job_1"  pwd ; bsub -Ip -w "done(job_1) && file(exist(NEW_FILE))" pwd . so I can't able to forward with the provided solutions

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste your existing script to your question. Format it as a code block, e.g. by using the `{}` tool of the editor field. What is `NEW_FILE`? A variable that contains the file name or (a placeholder for) the actual file name? What is your OS? What shell do you use?

Comment: Your edit "OS - Unix/Linux" does not provide more information than the existing tags `linux` and `unix`. There is no OS "Unix/Linux". Please name the actual operating system(s) or Linux distributions you use.

Comment: As far as I found out, the `bsub` command seems to be IBM specific. Do I understand correct that you want to submit both jobs using `bsub` at the same time and want the second job to wait for the successful exit of the first job and the existing file? What's the point in having two jobs? Wouldn't it be easier to combine both into one job and handle the condition internally? Otherwise you could create a third job that checks the existence of the file and exits with corresponding result. This would make the conditions more simple.